# How can i manipulate getopt so that it can accept *char in the options parameter?

Tags: c, linux

currently I am trying to make a linux command that will accept a *char and replace it with another specified *char. I understand that getopt takes 3 parameters, the final one being the options which only takes single characters as arguments. So i may be able to do something like:

```
./replace a ay b ing hello-world.txt
```

Will give me something along the lines of "in the text file hello-world, replace the strings of ay with the strings of ing.
What i'd potentially like to do is just be able to say

```
./replace ay ing hello-world.txt
```

and have the same effect. If someone could point me in the right direction, i'd very much appreciate it.

I hope this was clear enough. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's your question after all? Can you show us some code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: If that's the totality of where you want to go with the exercise you don't really need `getopt` at all.  Since everything is positional you could just as easily process the argv array yourself.  If you are going to add more parms or want the ability to switch them around e.g. `./replace -oing -iay hello-world.txt` then getopt may be worth the trouble.

Comment: Yes, asking how to use `getopt` in a situation where you don't want to have any actual options suggests that a simpler solution may be available.